# Is there a way to measure the height of what's visible to the user in his website?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to measure the height of the **visible content** area (that means - the top side of it is located where I start to see the site's content and that it ends where I have the windows or mac task panel) in Javascript somehow. It varies from browser to browser and whether I have other panels in the browser then it changes its size.

How can I get this data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a few useful Javascript (not jQuery) tools you can use to find this:

```
document.body.offsetWidth
document.body.offsetHeight
```

These find the Width and Height of the body element (so unless you've done something strange to the body element, then this should work).

You also have:

```
window.innerWidth
window.innerHeight
```

These would give you the width of the browser viewport, like antimatterfish said.

Comment: Unfortunately, things are [a bit more complicated](http://annevankesteren.nl/2007/08/cssom-mess). Better use a library.

Comment: @Pumbaa80: That's very interesting...maybe I hadn't searched hard enough, but several sources used this method. I tested it and it worked as well. Well, like they said, browsers always find a way to disagree.

Comment: document.body.offsetWidth is good enough in most cases, but fails if the `html` element has `margin` or `padding`. http://jsfiddle.net/742Ej/

Comment: window.innerHeight is what I was looking for - thanks! To get the visible height of the browser (and not the whole content that I need the scroll-bar to see it)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean `$(window).height();` and `$(window).width();` ? "window" measures the browser viewport...

Comment: Note that this is a solution for jquery, not for plain JavaScript.

Comment: How would jQuery not be JavaScript?